# PSQL database creation from script

Tags: scripting, transactions, psql

I have an issue with automatic database creation. I have created create_database.sql file with following code:

```
BEGIN;
\i schema.sql
\i domains.sql
\i sequences.sql
\i tables.sql
\i dane/insert_users.sql
\i dane/insert_default_expenses.sql
\i dane/insert_default_incomes.sql
\i dane/insert_default_payments.sql
\i dane/insert_user_incomes.sql
\i dane/insert_user_expenses.sql
\i dane/insert_user_payments.sql
\i dane/insert_expenses.sql
\i dane/insert_incomes.sql
\i procedures.sql
\i views.sql
COMMIT;
```

I would like to automatically create database using that transaction. So I am typing inside SQL SHELL:

```
psql budget < 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyy\create_database.sql'
```

There is no error returned but also DB is not being updated. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Do let me know if the solution that i provided works for you or you are still stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running a SQL file you need to provide the file by using the following command

```
./psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -f 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyy\create_database.sql'
```

Also in create_database.sql you need to provide full path for all sql files that you are executing from inside the tracnsaction block e.g

```
\i C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yyy\schema.sql
```